# Is there a way to remove a row in a list in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have created a quiet simple list in SwiftUI and want to make it editable, like a tableView in UIKit. I want to remove a row in the list with the all known gesture (swipe from, the right to the left).

I have tried to make with a button above the list, but it doesn't look nice an is not practicable for my app.

```
struct singleIsland: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name:String
}

var islands = [
singleIsland(id: 0, name: "Wangerooge"),
singleIsland(id: 1, name: "Spiekeroog"),
singleIsland(id: 2, name: "Langeoog")
]

var body: some View {
    VStack {

        List(islands) { island in
            Text(island.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the specific issue here. Can you remove a row in a list? Absolutely - watch the "Building your first app" session from WWDC. Basically, if you add `@State` to your array declaration then any view with `islands` will automatically be updated. Are you having an issue with animations? `List1 should pretty much handle anything pretty easily. Or is your issue that *"...it doesn't look nice..."*? If that your issue, please give us details why - usually a modifier or two (or a custom cell) can do the trick.

Answer (score 10):

```swift
struct SingleIsland {
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var islands = [
        SingleIsland(name: "Wangerooge"),
        SingleIsland(name: "Spiekeroog"),
        SingleIsland(name: "Langeoog")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(islands.identified(by: \.name)) { island in
                Text(island.name)
            }.onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
    }

    private func delete(with indexSet: IndexSet) {
        indexSet.forEach { islands.remove(at: $0) }
    }
}
```

Wrapping the data in a `@State` makes sure the view is redrawn if it changes.

---

**Note**:

I'm getting compilers errors if the `List` is built this way:

```
List(data) { item in
 [...]
}
```

It will complain that `onDelete` does not exist for the `List`.

My workaround is to use a `ForEach` inside the `List`, and the `onDelete` function on it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is very straight forward with SwiftUI.

Updating your code like this...

```
struct SingleIsland: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name:String
}

struct IslandListView: View {
    @State private var islands = [
        SingleIsland(id: 0, name: "Wangerooge"),
        SingleIsland(id: 1, name: "Spiekeroog"),
        SingleIsland(id: 2, name: "Langeoog")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(islands.identified(by: \.name)) { island in
                Text(island.name)   
            }.onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
    }

    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        islands.remove(at: offsets)
    }
}
```

This will allow your view to swipe to delete rows.

Using `@State` sets up your view to depend on the `islands` array. Any update to that array will trigger the view to reload. So by deleting an item from the array it will animate the change to the list.

Comment: Doesn't compile for me - `mac OS 10.15` / `Xcode 11 Beta` - the errors are the following: [image](https://i.imgur.com/S4j6ZS2.png).

Comment: @MatteoPacini I was relying on the WWDC code actually working. Haha :D

Comment: my take on WWDC code: "if it was on a slide, it doesn't work"

Comment: If you want it to compile, use this: ```islands.remove(atOffsets: offsets)```

Comment: @sfung3 apologies. If you’d like to edit the answer it will improve it for everyone. Thanks 

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the list:

```
.onDelete { $0.forEach { islands.remove(at: $0) } }
```

After you turning `islands` into an `@State`

Answer (score 2):

you can not do that with a static list.

in the real world your list of islands would probably come from the outside of your view anyway.

we use your struct:

```
[...]
struct singleIsland: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name:String
}
[...]
```

and create an bindable Object to hold those islands

```
[...]
class IslandStore : BindableObject {

   let didChange = PassthroughSubject<IslandStore, Never>()

   var islands : [singleIsland] {
       didSet { didChange.send(self) }
   }

   init (islands: [singleIsland] = []){
       self.islands = islands
   } 
}
[...]
```

you need to import combine to use BindableObject

```
[...]
import SwiftUI
import Combine
[...]
```

your view now binds the island store
the *.onDelete(perform: delete)* automatically adds the swipe left to delete function. We have to code the delete function tho:

```
[...]
struct ForTesting : View {
    @ObjectBinding var store = IslandStore()
    var body: some View {
        List {

            ForEach(store.islands) { island in
                Text(island.name)
                }.onDelete(perform: delete)

        }
    }

    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {

        // theres seems to be a bug that prevents us from using atOffsets
        // so we convert to index
        guard let index = Array(offsets).first else { return }

        store.islands.remove(at: index)
    }
}
[...]
```

and while we are at it we add a *EditButton()* and a title. We have to wrap our list in a *NavigationView* to do this

```
[...]
struct ForTesting : View {
    @ObjectBinding var store = IslandStore()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {

                ForEach(store.islands) { island in
                    Text(island.name)
                    }.onDelete(perform: delete)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Islands"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())

        }
    }

    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {

        // theres seems to be a bug that prevents us from using atOffsets
        // so we convert to index
        guard let index = Array(offsets).first else { return }

        store.islands.remove(at: index)
    }
}
[...]
```

change your DEBUG section to initialise the islands store and hand it over to your view:

```
#if DEBUG

var islands = [
    singleIsland(id: 0, name: "Wangerooge"),
    singleIsland(id: 1, name: "Spiekeroog"),
    singleIsland(id: 2, name: "Langeoog"),
    singleIsland(id: 3, name: "Baltrum")
]

struct ForTesting_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ForTesting(store: IslandStore(islands:islands))
    }
}

#endif
```

[image: viewwithdelete]

[complete code](https://gist.github.com/mimo74/738f087928fc7d80af93a7e31c3af29a)